# How to connect a customized Dispform to a different list?

Tags: custom-form, wss-3.0, sharepoint-designer

I have two lists (List A and List B) that were created from the same list  template.

The Dispform for List A was customized (some fields were cut out and others were rearranged).  The customized Dispform works perfectly with List A.

I’ve copied the customized DispForm to the folder for List B (List A and B were created from the same template)  and then connected the customized DispForm through the Supporting Files tab on the List Properties dialogue box for List B.

However, when I try to display the data in List B, I get the following error: **“Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Windows SharePoint Services-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.”**

I’m guessing this has something to do with customized DispForm having some code in it that prevents it from pulling in data from List B.

I’m using WSS 3.0 and SharePoint Designer 2007.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been awhile since I have done this sort of thing, but I am pretty sure the list GUID is set within the DataForm and needs to be updated.  Even though both lists were provisioned from the same template, they still have unique GUIDs.  It should be set near the top of the form definition code.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I was able to find the GUID in the DispForm. It shows up a few different times.
It's mostly in the <DataSources> </DataSources> section of the DispForm.  I got the new GUID for my new list and then decoded it using this webpage: http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php

I did a search and replace for the old GUID in the DispForm.

The DispForm now works with the new list.